# Which type of data and when should I initialize in the vuex state?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuex

I'm starting to learn about vuex. I have the question should I set this data from the Store or should I load it on the component?

For example, In my app, I load all users (firebase) from a Store Action and read it from the Getters, but when it comes to load one user data, should I fetch it from the state and then to the component or from the component itself?

I just want to make sure to make my life easier when updating or adding a new feature on the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your store should be your **only source of truth** for global state.

This means that any component that **read** data should read from the store. This ensures consistency. Of course each component may need some local data, that it gets using other means and can alter the data that it gets from the store, but it should read from there.

Now you only have a dilemma regarding who should **write** to the store (using mutations and actions). This depends heavily on your use cases. It is perfectly acceptable to **write** from the components itself.

There are use cases where populating some data from outside any component makes sense. Probably the most common case is auth credentials. It is easier and cleaner to populate auth credentials before mounting the app for instance so you have one choke point for dealing with authed/unauthed users.

Bottom line is, **writing** to the store depends on your use case and there's no silver bullet here.